# Example Multiple Async Await Calls Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I need to make an unknown number of api calls, up to 5 max probably. But most samples I've seen show only a couple of async calls so are effectively hard coded to the number of calls being made.

This is what I came up with as a demonstration, it has an array with three sleep times in it to simulate an API call of variable duration. The main function should wait until all three calls are finished.

It works but is this the right way to go about it?

```js
const sleep = async(milliseconds) => {
  await sleepMain(milliseconds);
  console.log(`Awake: ${milliseconds}`);
  let value = {
    sleep: milliseconds
  };
  return value;
}

const sleepMain = (milliseconds) => {
  console.log(`Sleeping ${milliseconds}`)
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

const asyncTest = async() => {

  arrayTest = [1000, 3000, 5000];
  arrayTestResult = Array();

  arrayTest.forEach(function(element) {
    console.log('Start Sleep: ' + element);
    arrayTestResult.push(sleep(element));
  });

  const syncThing = await Promise.all(arrayTestResult);

  console.log(syncThing);
  return syncThing;

}

const main = async() => {
  console.log('Start Main');
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Running...';
  await asyncTest();
  console.log('Finish Main');
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Finished - See Console Log';
}

main();
```

```html
<h1>Multi Thread Async Test</h1>
<p>Runs the array of sleep lengths (in async) and completes when all done</p>
<p>sleep and sleepMain are used to simulate an API call of variable response time</p>
<h2 id='message'></h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kanineAU/yv21Leqf/

Comment: Side note: You can't do multi-threading in JS environments. What you're doing here is parallel async calls.

Comment: Passing array of promises to Promise.all() is quite common...yes

Comment: Title edited to avoid confusion relating to the definition of multi-threading.

Comment: can use `async.queue` if you want (and like the `async` library)

Comment: It's fine to use Promise.all(), but if you have "unknown" number of API calls, you may not want to run them all in parallel. If you only want to have e.g. 2 running at once, but queue them all up at the same time, look into the `async` library's `queue`.

Comment: Using the `Array()` constructor, a `forEach` loop and `push` is a bit weird - you should just have used `map`. But the usage of `await` and `Promise.all` is really fine.

Comment: @NikKyriakides You can do multi threading in JS environments using webWorkers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API

Comment: @Blindman67 That's *multiprocessing* not multithreading. Multithreading implies shared memory, which WebWorkers don't allow (you can only copy and send messages back and forth). WebWorker contexts are isolated, separate processes.

Comment: @NikKyriakides SharedArrayBuffers provide shared memory across workers. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads

Comment: @Blindman67 I stand corrected